# How can I convert a System.Windows.Input.Key to a number?

Tags: c#, keyboard, converters

I'm using an event `PreviewKeyDown`, and am adding the key in a list of key, as shown in the example below:

```
    List<Key> keys = new List<Key>();
    private void MDIChildBackground_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {        

        keys.Add(e.Key);
    }
```

Then I wanted to take the keys from the list and convert to integer.

Example:

```
    int number=int.parse(keys[0].ToString());
```

ps: will only be typed numbers

But the problem is in converting to string
because when I type one (1) in keyboard and convert to string
the string value is "D1" and not "1".
Soon, if I try to convert this string to integer, it will give exception.

Now, how can I handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.virtualkeyfromkey%28v=vs.100%29) method to convert a WPF Key into a Win32 Virtual-Key. It will return the integer value of the pressed key.

For example, if you hit the <kbd>T</kbd> key it will return 84.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you're only dealing with number keys, then the following should work (I'm not that familiar with Windows.Input - is that WPF stuff?);

```
int Number = -1;

if( keys[0] >= Key.D0 && keys[0] <= Key.D9 )
   Number = keys[0] - Key.D0;
```

Repeat for other keys in list.

Comment: Just noticed it's essentially L.B answer, but using the correct namespace/types. Will update answer to more closley match his.